# Bean validation error with hibernate and GWT

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, gwt

We have web based application which have UI in GWT and uses spring at middle ware. It uses uses hibernate + JPA at ORM layer. Transaction is managed by Spring and its local transaction (Not JTA). Whenever a transaction is committed, its throwing an Null pointer @ hibernate bean validation layer. I have enabled logs for Spring and Hibernate but it does not get logged in those log files rather it gets directed to localhost file of tomcat logs. My question

```
1.> What could be the reason for this error?
2.> Is there way to enable more detailed logs in tomcat (Already have tried loggers in tomcat log file but unable to see any result)
```

Following is the Stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:108)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:79)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:236)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
... 49 more
```

Complete Stack Trace

```
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:551)
at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:37)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.login(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
... 34 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:108)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:79)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:236)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
... 49 more
```

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is because of an NPE. I can't help you find out why unless I see some source code.

Comment: But NPE is in a class of hibernate, not a bean which is part of my APP. And thats why I have asked whether there is a way to get more logs?